# updating state using hooks in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I want to change active to true in my object, in the console log i have an updated version of the state however i cannot update the state itself, i feel im going about this the wrong way.  any help would be fantastic thankyou, for sure there is a similar post somewhere but i have failed to find anything.

```
const [components, setComponents] = useState([
  {
    compName: "Weather",
    path: 'weather',
    active: false
  },
  {
    compName: "Tasks",
    path: 'tasks',
    active: false
  },
])
                                                      

 function onActivateHandler(){
      setComponents((prevComponents) => {
        const copy = [...prevComponents]
        let newState = {...copy[1]}
        newState.active = true
        console.log(newState)
    
        return  {...prevComponents}
      })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just only need to generate a new reference for the whole array.

Another thing that I noticed is that you are returning an object from your `setComponents()` function. Since the state variable `components` is an array, i think you need to return an array.

Also, write `onActivateHandler()` method as an arrow function to bind it to the component context, just in case, normally is what you would want to do.

I would write it like this (I toggle the active value justo to demonstrate):

```js
const myComponent = () => {
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([
        {
           compName: "Weather",
           path: "weather",
           active: false,
        },
        {
           compName: "Tasks",
           path: "tasks",
           active: false,
        },
    ]);

    const onActivateHandler = () => {
        setComponents((prevComponents) => {
           // update the array reference
           const newState = [...prevComponents];
           newState[1].active = !newState[1].active;

           // Your state variable is an array,
           // so you need to return an array
           return [...prevComponents];
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onActivateHandler}>Click</button>
            <div>{components[1].active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}</div>
        </>
    )
};
```

As `lawrence-witt` say below not creating a new object inside the new array may lead to not re-rendering in some cases, but in your simple case the code above works fine, since is the array reference what react is tracking on, and not the reference of the objects inside. You can spread the `newState[1]` into a new object if you need to, but you will need to delete the older one form the state array.

Cheers!

Comment: This is not such a good idea because without cloning the object you will retain its reference and mutate the state before setting it. This often leads to no rerender being triggered.

Comment: No, sure, I'm aware of that.  I just understand that the reference being tracked by react is  the reference of the array. But I could be wrong. I will test it and edit if necessary.

Comment: The danger here isn't just that React won't make a proper equality check on the returned state and rerender that component, but that any subcomponents that take `components[1].active` as a prop will behave in unexpected ways when that value is prematurely mutated. I would recommend decoupling references whenever modifying any React state.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to return your cloned, modified object alongside the rest of the `prevComponents`. At the moment you are returning just the old state, so nothing will change (apart from the fact that you are accidentally returning an object, not an array).

Edit: doesn't look so pretty now but it is safe.

```
function onActivateHandler(){
    setComponents((prevComponents) => {
      const copy = [...s];
      const newState = {...copy.splice(1, 1)[0]}
      newState.active = true;
      return [...copy, newState];
    })
 }
```

Comment: ok thanks, so this worked, only its causing duplicate of the state each time instead of replacing the old state..

Comment: Right, I forgot you'd have to splice it out. Just a mo.